# Is it more profitable to mine non-SegWit blocks

Tags: bitcoin-core, transaction-fees, mining-profitability, segregated-witness

The fees for a SegWit address are lower than non-Segwit ones. Is there less fees per block with Segwit blocks? Is it less profitable to mine Segwit blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "segwit" block does not exclusively contain segwit transactions; it can contain both segwit and non-segwit. "Non-segwit" blocks contain exclusively non-segwit transactions because it does not have the requisite segwit commitments. Since segwit blocks can contain both types of transactions, it is actually less profitable to mine non-segwit blocks as you will be missing transactions that segwit blocks can contain.

Comment: Plus more SegWit transactions for into a block and that block can become larger than non-SegWit blocks, so total fees are actually higher.